# No space to snapshot on xenserver - Catch 22 to move the VMs

Tags: linux, xenserver, xen

I am trying to move some VMs from one Xenserver onto another one but am stuck in a catch 22 situation. I have 3 VMs running on this server all on one storage repository. I don't have space to snapshot my smallest server (need 250GB, have 91GB), xencenter won't allow me to shrink the size of the virtual disk (set at 250GB but I am only using 15GB on the server).

Any ideas what I can do? I have loads of space on other repositories and I'm just trying to migrate them off so I can put bigger HDDs in.

Worse case scenario would be to remove / re-install the least important server but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fullcopy the VM from the xenconsole gui to the other server SR. Be in a pool the prereq :)

The fullcopy allow you to move between SR the VM.

I dont see why you need a snapshot, trying to move the snapshot while the server is running? I dont recommand that way. A fullcopy of the vm will take the server correctly, as the move can take some time. (thus the state of old server can be differant than new server on new sr because of the time it took to copy)

Comment: Ok, so if I move the Xenserver into a pool with another one, I'll be able to do this? Do you have any documentation on the fullcopy option as it's not something I've seen?

Comment: Oh wait, I've just found the option for Move to my other SR and it's now moving. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, this made me look again and see the option so was very useful :)

Comment: My pleasure! Glad it was usefull :)